# Convert DateTime.Ticks to MySQL DateTime in query

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a integer column in MySql storing the DateTime.Ticks.

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001

How can I convert this to a DateTime in a query? I've tried many things, but cannot get it to work.

For the ticks 634128921500016150 I hope to get the mysql datetime '2010-06-23 12:06:50'

I would have believed the following should work, but it gives '4009-06-22 12:15:50.001600'. It seems it's off by 2001 years, 1 day and 9 minutes... If the years and days is consistent, I can just fix it manually, but the minutes seems a little odd.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('0000-01-01 00:00:00',
  INTERVAL 634128921500016150/10000000 SECOND_MICROSECOND);
```

I've tried adding more zeros, but it never matches :|

I also tried Jon Skeet's suggestion, but it gives nearly the same result (some fraction of a second different)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than adding using SECOND_MICROSECOND, try just adding via MICROSECOND:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  INTERVAL 634121049314500000/10 MICROSECOND);
```

EDIT: I've just worked out why the years are so wrong. MySQL's [minimum date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) is the year 1000. So I suggest you change it to:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  INTERVAL (634121049314500000 - base_ticks)/10 MICROSECOND);
```

where `base_ticks` is the value of the ticks from `new DateTime(1001, 1, 1).Ticks`.

Heck, you could rebase wherever you want (e.g. 2000) - that might even work round the 9 minutes issue. It's possible that it's making up for leap seconds over the years, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives the same result. I've updated my post with a bit more details.

Comment: @simendsjo: I've made an edit - you should be using 0001 instead of 0000. I know that sounds like it'll only make 1 year of difference instead of 2000, but *maybe* 0 means something special in mysql?

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm! base_ticks needs to be from year 2001 instead of 1001. '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is a special value for blank date in mysql, much like DateTime.MinValue

Comment: Hello, is it possible to do it in Hive? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502264/how-to-convert-net-datetime-ticks-to-hive-datetime-in-query

Answer (score 4):

Found myself doing the same thing today.  Between Jon's answer and the comments I was able to figure it out, but here it is as a function, all wrapped up with a nice bow on it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TicksToDateTime(ticks BIGINT) RETURNS datetime DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CAST(DATE_ADD('2001-01-01 00:00:00', 
   INTERVAL (ticks - 631139040000000000)/10 MICROSECOND) AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found this useful.  But because I was looking for a higher precision value, I changed both references of `DATETIME` to `DATETIME(6)`.

Answer (score 0):

And for those of us coding against SQL Server Compact Edition, the above bow wrapped function is written in a query as:

> Select DATEADD(second, (CAST(([TickField]-631139040000000000) AS
>   FLOAT)/10000000), '2001-01-01 00:00:00' ) From [Table]

The previous code does not work in Compact Edition. It took a while to figure out, so I thought worth including.

I suppose it would work in other SQL versions too but haven't tested it. It has the advantage of being part of a query, so no function needs to be created.

Cheers.