# Can we convert Ticks to datetime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a column from a C# application whose value is in Ticks. Is there a MySQL query to convert it into DATETIME with milliseconds?

Comment: Similar issue here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100666/convert-datetime-ticks-to-mysql-datetime-in-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MySQL DATETIME will not hold milliseconds, see [Bug 27838](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27838).
Therefore I think you can only do this:

```
DateTime sqlDateTime = new DateTime(someTickVariable);
```

You can then use `sqlDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to get a MySQL conforming String like `2010-12-31 14:00:00`.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL's datetime is second-resolution. If you need more, store the ticks (epoch milliseconds) in a bigint or something.