# How to convert .net DateTime.Ticks to Hive DateTime in query?

Tags: c#, datetime, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I have log file with a column in DateTime.Ticks (635677577653488758) which i am trying to convert it to Date in Hadoop Hive.

First i tried the code block below on MySql and it worked. But the same code didn't work in Hive because date_add function works with INT.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2001-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL (MAX(f.date) - 631139040000000000)/10 MICROSECOND);
```

Then i will format it like this...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MyDateFromTicks, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ');
```

How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. I am writing it down here so if anyone comes this far can check the answer :)

My Ticks: 635683895215023579

EPOCH Ticks: 621355968000000000

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST((635683895215023579 - 621355968000000000)/10000000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

Comment: Careful - Unix time (and the Unix epoch) are always UTC based, and thus refer to a specific moment in time.  `DateTime` ticks are based on the date and time values, without regard for the `.Kind` associated with the `DateTime`.  Those ticks *might* refer to a specific UTC-based moment in time, but could just as easily be based on the computer's local time zone that wrote them originally, or on some other time zone entirely.  You'd need to know more about the context under which they were created.  Without that context, you might get back a different date/time than you started with.

Answer (score 0):

write an UDF in java .. Use SimpleDateFormat class to convert the data into date

Comment: I will try it asap. Is there any other native hive way that you know? Thanks.